# Is this a JSON array, or named elements, or ? : "options": [ "{name=convertible, fee=110.0}" ]

Tags: json

This appears to be some kind of string array, but I have not encountered it before.

```
"options": [ "{name=convertible, fee=110.0}" ]
```

or, more fully:

```
"costCenters": [ {"options": [ "{name=convertible, fee=110.0}" ]} ]
```

(Using C# json parser)

Is it one big string that I need to unpack, or is it proper JSON?

If it is JSON, what is the flavor of these elements?

Comment: It is proper json, with an object with one property, `options`, that has the value of type "array", with the array having only one (string) element `"{name=convertible, fee=110.0}"`.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you. So I then need to parse the string myself, as that is the smallest JSON component, correct?

Comment: Correct. And that string does not contain valid json, because the names are not in quotes.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you. Remember in the bad old days when some coders would "hand code" XML (rather than going through an XML parser)? I think that is what this is. A developer, instead of doing it properly, shoves a string into the output that is pseudo-JSON, and leaves it to us, the API consumer to deal with the mess.  I guess the bad old days are still with us. Ack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string

```
"{name=convertible, fee=110.0}"
```

is a valid JSON string, but the string

```
{name=convertible, fee=110.0}
```

is not valid JSON, though it could be mapped to a JSON object with keys "name" and "fee" in one of several ways.

To ascertain whether a given text is valid JSON, you could use jsonlint.com or other similar services.